# Detect in list2 if there are any strings (whole or part of bigger string) that is contained in list1

Tags: r, text, pattern-matching, match, matching

I have two lists:

```
list1<-list("q","w","e","r","t")
list2<-list("a","a","aq","c","f","g")
```

I need a code that will give `TRUE` because `q` is in the third cell of `list2`. I need to search for every cell of `list1` in `list2`. I mean that I need to search every cell of `list2` for any strings that are contained in every cell of `list1`. Matching should be as for the whole match but also for partial (if string from `list1` is a part of the bigger string in `list2`) and in both cases I need to receive `TRUE`.

Comment: Please add expected output

Comment: Yes, unclear if you want a list output or a single TRUE/FALSE here

Comment: @PoGibas "I need a code that will give `TRUE`" So I need to get `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: `lapply(list1, grepl, list2)`

Comment: @CalumYou Single `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
any(sapply(list1, grepl, list2))
# [1] TRUE
```

Or equivalently

```
greplv <- Vectorize(grepl, 'pattern')
any(greplv(list1, list2))
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if the list input is particularly important here in that case. Here is a way that avoids using any iteration functions like `apply`. We can collapse the input list into a single regular expression pattern and then check the whole of the second list with it. You may need to be careful if you have any special characters in list1, though that is the case for any string matching method.

```r
library(stringr)
list1 <- list("q", "w", "e", "r", "t")
list2 <- list("a", "a", "aq", "c", "f", "g")

pat <- unlist(list1) %>% str_c(collapse = "|")

list2 %>%
  unlist %>%
  str_detect(pat) %>%
  any
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure that `library(stringr)` is needed? I cannot find that library to install and also it seems that code works without it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I need matching the *whole* cell from list1 to match *whole* or *part* of the cell of list2. Your code matches *whole* cell or *part* of the cell from list1 to *whole* or part of the cell of list2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56174663/1601703 answer does way I need. But I think that problem is not with your code but is with my not very accurate formulation of the question.

Comment: As far as I can tell this answer should always give the same output as mine. To test that, change the first element of `list1` to `"dq"`. Then part of one element in `list1` matches part of an element in `list2`, but the output is (correctly) `FALSE`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan You are right. Clum You Sorry for the confusion.