# Match the whole cell of list1 to beginning of all cells of list2

Tags: r, string, pattern-matching, match, matching

The current question is the extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56174477/detect-in-list2-if-there-are-any-strings-whole-or-part-of-bigger-string-that-i).
From previous question I have a code:

```
list1<-list("q","w","e","r","t")
list2<-list("a","a","aq","c","f","g")

any(sapply(list1, grepl, list2))
# [1] TRUE
```

It matches one by one whole string from every cell of *list1* to one by one to any part of the string in *list2* in every cell. If there is any match I receive as an output single `TRUE`. Now I need to modify it like that only beginning of the string in every cell should be matched in *list2*. For example, if I have

```
list1<-list("q","w","e","r","t")
list2<-list("a","a","aq","c","f","g")
```

OR

```
list1<-list("q","w","e","r","t")
list2<-list("a","a","aqaa","c","f","g")
```

the result should be `FALSE`. But if I have:

```
list1<-list("q","w","e","r","t")
list2<-list("a","a","qa","c","f","g")
```

the answer should be `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same method as before with `startsWith`. You just have to flip the list order (note that it is checking if any elements in `list2` start with a letter in `list1`.

```
list1<-list("q","w","e","r","t")
list2<-list("a","a","qa","c","f","g")

any(sapply(list2, startsWith, unlist(list1)))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Your example does exactly what I need. You understand the question correctly. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the anchor `regex` here as well. Note that I am changing your original input to be more instructive on how this will look.

```
> list1<-list("q","w","e","r","t")
> list2<-list("a","a","aq","c","rs", "t")
> 
> lapply(list1, function(x) grepl(paste0("^", x, "$"), list2))
[[1]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[4]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[5]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Note that this should work with `sapply` as well.

**EDIT: TO GIVE MORE DETAIL**

Here is what your results would look like (without `any`) if you use `sapply`

```
sapply(list1, function(x) grepl(paste0("^", x, "$"), list2))

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Now using `any` on the original output with `lapply` vs. the `sapply` output would look as follows:

```
lapply(lapply(list1, function(x) grepl(paste0("^", x, "$"), list2)), any)
[[1]]
[1] FALSE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE

[[4]]
[1] FALSE

[[5]]
[1] TRUE
```

And for `sapply`

```
any(sapply(list1, function(x) grepl(paste0("^", x, "$"), list2)))
[1] TRUE
```

But if you want to `apply` to your outputs from the original `lapply` code, you can use:

```
sapply(lapply(list1, function(x) grepl(paste0("^", x, "$"), list2)), any)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

It depends on the output you want.

Comment: How can receive single `TRUE` if there is any `TRUE`? I tried `any(lapply(list1, function(x) grepl(paste0("^", x, "$"), list2)))` but it gives me the error.

Comment: Set the result of this to `k` and use `lapply(k, any)`

Comment: Looks like it may not have caught `"r"` and `"rs"` (assuming I understand the question correctly). Otherwise, great edit / explanation!

Comment: I thought you want exact match, if you want partial match, then you can take out the anchors in the `paste0` functoin

Comment: Like I said, I may not have understood the question correctly. But I thought it was all of list 1 compared to the first letter in list 2. Can you add some clarity, @vasili111?

Comment: This code: `list1<-list("q","q","q","q","q")` 
 `list2<-list("a","a","aq","qc","s", "t")` `any(sapply(list1, function(x) grepl(paste0("^", x, "$"), list2)))` gives false but it should give true.

Comment: Why? Because of "qc"? Or because of "aq"? Or both?

Comment: @akash87 because of `qc` it should give `TRUE`, because it starts with `q` (which is in a cell in of `list1`. But if we replace `qc` with for example `xx` it should give `FALSE` because `aq` contains `q` BUT does not starts with it.

Comment: Gotcha, then you want to remove the "$" from all `paste0` codes. It will anchor the first but will not look beyond that